# IE csrf cookienot present when opening from outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, outlook

I have Asp .Net MVC 5 application that sends emails during busines flow. 
There is a link that leads to the acceptance form within application, so user should just click Email link, get form and submit it. Nothing special.

It works ok when I'm opening the page in a "normal way" from command line(with url as an argument) , but i get

```
 System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException
```

whith message:

> "  The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is
>   not present."

when trying to open this same page from Outlook link.

I have no idea how to fix it. The problem is not present in other browsers,but offcorse IE is a Standard in my corp. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Sure it's not cached in IE? i.e. and old version of the page has loaded with an old Request Verification Token?